# Elasticsearch context suggester, bool on contexts

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using context suggester and am wondering if we can set the scope of the context to be used for suggestions rather that using all contexts.

Currently the query needs to match all contexts. Can we add an "OR" operation on the contexts and/or specify which context to use for  a particular query?

Taking the example from [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-adding-context-suggestions) :
Mapping :

```
PUT /venues/poi/_mapping
{
  "poi" : {
    "properties" : {
      "suggest_field": {
        "type": "completion",
        "context": {
          "type": { 
            "type": "category"
          },        
          "location": { 
            "type": "geo",
            "precision" : "500m"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I index a document :

```
 {
  "suggest_field": {
    "input": ["The Shed", "shed"],
    "output" : "The Shed - fresh sea food",
    "context": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 51.9481442,
        "lon": -5.1817516
      },      
      "type" : "restaurant"
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "suggest" : {
    "text" : "s",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "suggest_field",
      "context": {
        "location": {
          "value": {
            "lat": 51.938119,
            "lon": -5.174051
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I query using only one Context ("location" in the above example) it gives an error, I need to pass both the contexts, is it possible to specify which context to use? Or pass something like a "Context_Operation" parameter set to "OR".

Comment: Is it ok to index the category like this : [any, restaurant] ("any" will be included in all indexed docs by default) and when you performing the query, pass "any" as category + "location" ?

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 choices:

First you add all available type values as default in your mapping (not scalable)

```
{
  "poi" : {
    "properties" : {
      "suggest_field": {
        "type": "completion",
        "context": {
          "type": { 
            "type": "category",
            "default": ["restaurant", "pool", "..."]
          },        
          "location": { 
            "type": "geo",
            "precision" : "500m"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second option, you add a default value to every indexed document, and you add only this value as default

Mapping:

```
{
  "poi" : {
    "properties" : {
      "suggest_field": {
        "type": "completion",
        "context": {
          "type": { 
            "type": "category",
            "default": "any"
          },        
          "location": { 
            "type": "geo",
            "precision" : "500m"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Document:

```
{
  "suggest_field": {
    "input": ["The Shed", "shed"],
    "output" : "The Shed - fresh sea food",
    "context": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 51.9481442,
        "lon": -5.1817516
      },      
      "type" : ["any", "restaurant"]
    }
  }
}
```