# Elasticsearch suggest condition check

Tags: elasticsearch

> Here below is my DB data.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("572c957244ae959c6517bcb2"), 
"name":"first",
"rating" : 2.0, 
"private" : "true"
}
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("572c957244ss959c6517bcb2"), 
"name":"first",
"rating" : 2.0, 
"private" : "false"
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("572c9dfef44ae959c6517bcb2"), 
"name":"first",
"rating" : 2.0, 
"private" : "false"
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("572c9dfef44ae959c6517bcb2"), 
"name":"first",
"rating" : 2.0, 
}
```

> I need to get other than "private" :"true" (i.e including json object without private filed) , in my elasticsearch .My elasticsearch query to fetch is as follow

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tellofy/_suggest?pretty' -d '
{"brand-suggest":  {"completion":"field":"nameSuggest","size":"5"},   "text":"first"}}'
```

> what I need to get the name along with private "false" and without that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tellofy/_suggest?pretty' -d '
{
   "brand-suggest": {
      "completion": {
         "field": "nameSuggest",
         "size": "5",
         "context": {
            "private": "false"
         }
      },
      "text": "first"
   }
}'
```

I think you will also have to set a default value "false" for the private-field in the mapping:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/tellofy/test/_mapping" -d'
{
   "test": {
      "properties": {
         "name": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "rating": {
            "type": "float"
         },
         "private": {
            "type": "boolean"
         },
         "nameSuggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "context": {
               "private": {
                  "type": "category",
                  "path": "private",
                  "default": false
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Haven't used the context suggesters myself in elasticsearch though. See the [Elasticsearch Context Suggester documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html#_category_query) for more info.

See also this question: [Elasticsearch context suggester, bool on contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842492/elasticsearch-context-suggester-bool-on-contexts)

Comment: Hi Neman , I tried above it throws following error when i put _suggest insted of _search in URL "nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[suggester [completion] doesn't expect any context]; " . If i put _search as you posted the following error occurs "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;.....

Comment: Is there any to give me solution for my above describe error.

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: elasticsearch 1.7.3

Comment: I think your mapping is missing a context, I've updated my answer above.