# ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-1.6.0

My code is

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/web/_suggest?pretty' -d '
{ "brand-suggest": {"completion": {"field": "nameSuggest","size":   "5","context": { "private": "false" }}, "text": "sampl"}}'
```

I have an error while trying in elasticsearch suggest query.

```
"index" : "webpage",
      "shard" : 4,
      "status" : 500,
      "reason" : "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[tellofy][4] ];  nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[suggester [completion] doesn't expect any context]; "
    }
```

What is the reason for the above error. I can't able to find the cause of that error.

Comment: Can you provide the mapping of the nameSuggest field?

Comment: zmy namesuggest is a jsonObject.
mappingJSON.put("nameSuggest", new JSONObject(
"{\"type\": \"completion\", \"analyzer\" : \"simple\", \"search_analyzer\" : \"simple\" , \"context\" : \"simple\"}"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nameSuggest` has a `completion` type but without `context`, so your suggest query is not allowed to specify a `context`

See the difference between [normal `completion` fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) and [`completion` fields with context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html)

If you wish to run the following query

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/web/_suggest?pretty' -d '{
  "brand-suggest": {
    "completion": {
      "field": "nameSuggest",
      "size": "5",
      "context": {
        "private": "false"
      }
    },
    "text": "sampl"
  }
}'
```

You need to change the mapping of your `nameSuggest` field to this i.e. add a context configuration section:

```
{
  "type": "completion",
  "analyzer": "simple",
  "search_analyzer": "simple",
  "context": {
    "private": {
      "type": "category",
      "path": "private"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr Val . thanks for your suggestion. , Initially i need to check whether it is correct . for that i run above curl command in my terminal. here you asked me to change my context ,  for terminal what i need to change in above curl... "context" .

Comment: You simply need to remove the `context` section from your query and it will work

Comment: But i need to check condition that what are all private ("false") along with my text ("samp1") .

Comment: Then you need the context :) There's no other way.

Comment: My actual question is in below link.
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995684/elasticsearch-suggest-condition-check/38999497#38999497"
Can you help, based on above link question.

Comment: I understand, but you need to modify your mapping as I suggested in order for this to work.

Comment: yes i got a solution . That is due to mapping issue ,After deleted my previous elasticsearch indexes and saved newly it works fine.